# Fix symlinks in a git repository

Tags: git, symlink

Some time ago now I updated my Debian operating system with a fresh install of strech from scratch instead of wheezy. That changed the paths to assets I had in my git repository to a format with localization and the new user name (e.g.: from `/home/esa/Documents/cv/cv.odt` to `/home/daniele/Documenti/cv/cv.odt`).

Now I want to fix my repository with the new paths for each assets. Should I write fixup commit(s) or instead try `filter-branch`?

Comment: Do you need to change the old commits? Seems like a normal commit will do.

Comment: The repository is local and I'm also experimenting a bit with git since I'm a beginner. I want to have all the commits consinstent with the new paths

Comment: Yes, you can use filter-branch to do this, though [filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is replacing it for most needs. However, unless you need to run those old commits there is no need to rewrite them. You can always rewrite them later, unrewriting them is much harder. You should also consider a strategy which does not hard code absolute paths everywhere. Part of learning Git is learning when it's not a Git problem.

Comment: I decided to abandon fixing symlinks with `filter-branch`/[`filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo). Instead I wrote a commit that stores the full files so from now on data should be correctly revisioned.